# how to debug this? Call to a member function result() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

Please Help.. im using **CODEIGNITER** 
I want to print the value of my userlevel and email using echo.. to know if im getting the right data from the database.. then suddenly this error keep bugging me.
beginner in CODEIGNITER need some help here.. thanks a lot!

in my controller:

```
if ($this->is_validated($rules))
{
        $where  = array('email' => $this->input->post('txt_email'));
        $data['query'] = $this->database_model->select_userlevel('userlevel', $where);
        $user = $data['query'];
        foreach($user->result() as $row)
        {
           echo $row->email;
           echo $row->userlevel;
        }
}
```

in my model:

```
public function select_userlevel($table, $where) 
{
    $this->db->where($where);
    $query =  $this->db->get($table);
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'no value';
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `return true` you need to return your query in model

**Model**

```
public function select_userlevel($table, $where) 
{
    $this->db->where($where);
    $query =  $this->db->get($table);
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
{
    return  $query;// return query here
}
else
{

    return false;
}
```

**Controller**

```
$user = $this->database_model->select_userlevel('userlevel', $where);
     foreach($user->result() as $row)
        {
       // your code here
      }
```

UPDATED FOR better solution and proper use of MVC.

Instead of return query you need to return data from your model

**MODEL**

```
public function select_userlevel($table, $where)
{
$this->db->where($where);
$query = $this->db->get($table);
if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
return $query->result(); // return your result
}
else
{

return false;
}
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$user = $this->database_model->select_userlevel('userlevel', $where);
foreach ($user as $row) {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: agreed. The problem is that you are never returning the results to your controller.

Comment: @CodeGodie agree with you . This is bad use of MVC . I am only pointing the wrong thing in OP code

Comment: hi @Saty, can you explain why this is bad use of MVC?

Comment: Fatching the result in controller is bad use .

Comment: Gotcha. yes I agree. the controller should only receive the results.

Answer (score 0):

`$user` is not an active record object, so it does not have a reference to the **result** method.

All of this logic belongs in the Model and not the Controller.

### Controller

```
public function doSomething()
{
   if( !$this->is_validated($rules) ) 
       return;

   $email = $this->input->post('txt_email');

   $users = $this->database_model->select_userlevel($email);

   // for debugging
   var_dump( $users )
   die();
}
```

### Model

```
public function select_userlevel($email)
{
    $query = $this->db->select()
                      ->where('email', $email)
                      ->get('userlevel');

    return ( $query->num_rows() > 0) ? $query->result() : false;
}
```

Comment: How is this different than @Saty 's answer?

Comment: It's not, he was just faster at typing the answer :)